# .gitignore to be properly applied across multiple machines and multiple branches

Tags: git, branch, rebase

We are 3 developers in our team and we of course have multiple projects of multiple branches across multiple machines.

We have fiddled around with git-ignoring a certain folder. What we have initially done is placing a .gitignore in the master branch on one machine. Then we used

`git rm -r --cached`

method to untrack the files on that machine.
That part works like a charm.
And that's just until another client pulls the commit in which that has happened and the entire folder is deleted.

Then we tried to back up the content to simply copy/paste it back in (not a pretty solution, but still), but then we encounter a problem when entering branches.

We tried both rebasing and merging the existing branches, and that similarly results in everything being deleted on machine 1 and 2 alike.

Does anybody have any idea how we can explain git on all machines to simply just ignore that folder, and not do any further actions on it? To stop tracking that folder and do it instantly across all branches?

We understand the mechanics of why this happens, but we have been unable to find a feasable work-around which doesn't require endless hours of careful work, where files can easily end up missing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

.gitignore is able to ignore directories too, add `<directoryname>/`to your .gitignore

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but we are aware of this. The problem is that this ignore instruction cannot be applied across branches and across machines without it first resulting in a ton of deleted files.

Comment: Why would it result in a ton of deleted files? Whatever files that are already in the directory will not be affected.
You just have to copy it across all the branches, and push to remote for your other machines to pull.
Or you have not been committing the changes in the directory?

Comment: That's what we saw happen when I pulled the creation of the .gitignore file and the command to git rm -r --cached on the directory. I even made sure to get the .gitignore in the branch first - still all files were deleted, even though Git was told not to care about that particular directory any more.

Comment: so you mean `git rm --cached` removed files from your working directory permanently? (i.e. you can't find it physically when you navigate to the path of the directory?)

Comment: @riwu, it is not `git rm --cached` that removes the files from the working directory, it is when other people than pull the repo down that *their* files are removed from their working directory.

Comment: Can you add the gitignore to a branch and link the url? I can test it.